# Create Audit Trail from SQL CDC

Tags: sql-server, audit, change-data-capture

I have a few tables on which I have enabled CDC. As each row in CDC table contains all the columns regardless if they were changed or not, so it becomes difficult to figure out only the changed data. Is there a way to create a single Audit Table with data in these CDC tables so that it shows Table Name, Column Name, Old Value, New Value from all CDC tables together. If this is possible then a better reporting can be done.

Thanks

Comment: What if more than one column's value changed in the same transaction?...how would you display that in the structure you requested?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose your table has columns PK, A & B. After an UPDATE the [CDC change table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server#change-table) will have entires like

```
__$operation  PK  A  B
           3   1  X  Y
           4   1  X  Z
```

omitting the other metadata tables for clarity. If this is [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)ed you get

```
__$operation  PK  Column  Value
           3   1  A       X
           3   1  B       Y
           4   1  A       X
           4   1  B       Z
```

The "before" rows (operation 3) can be separated from the "after" (operation 4) by a WHERE. It may be convenient to wrap each in a view or a CTE. Then the "before" can be joined to "after" on PK and Column. When the Value differs you have a row to insert into the audit table.

```
select
  'TheTableName' as TableName,
  a.Column,
  a.PK,
  b.Value as BeforeValue,
  a.Value as AfterValue
from dbo.Before b        -- a view
inner join dbo.After a   -- a view
  on a.PK = b.PK
  and a.Column = b.Column
where a.Value != b.Value;
```

For a generic audit table common to all application tables this format is good enough. You may decide to aggregate changes made together into a single audit row. This is probably best done as [JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server) these days, though [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server) and simple [string concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) are also options.

To handle more than one UPDATE to a row you will involve __$start_lsn as well as PK.